# How do you multi-sign a piece of data with multiple keys?

Tags: web3js, signature, multisignature

I'm aware how one can sign a message with a single key using `web3.eth.sign` or `helpeth`. How can multiple keys sign the same message? (preferably with an example using web3)

Answer (score 1):

There's no special trick to it. Multiple signatures are just that, *multiple* signatures, not one special mega-signature. You just iterate through the accounts that you want to sign with, and collect an array of signatures, which you then all provide to whatever needs them.

Example (untested):

```
var signatures = [];
for(var i=0; i<signingAccounts.length; i++) {
  signatures[i] = web3.eth.sign(signingAccounts[i], data);
}
```

Comment: are you sure? cause I've seen contracts which use the result of `sign = ecrecover(h,v,r,s)` and compare it against multiple address `if (sign==A && sign==B)`

Comment: I'll be darned, then. I've never heard or seen of these--do you have a link? (that said, an array of signatures is probably easier to work with.)

Comment: @d9ngle do you remember which contract does that? Would be interesting to read. Although I wonder if the comparison (logically can't be literally "sign == A && sign == B") is another form of comparing elements in the array, which would essentially be Matthew's implementation.